# не работают менеджеры tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

Не открываются менеджеры "server status, manager app, host manager".
нажимаю на соответствующие кнопки и tomcat начинает загружать страницу и больше ничего не происходит: ни в логах ни в браузере. Так происходит в Chrome но при этом он переходит на эти страницы в Edge.
но тем не менее в enge он неправильно деплоит архив
он вместо /project_name в менеджере проектов пишет C:.....\project_name , то-есть прописывает целиком путь к файлу и из-за этого он ругается в логах на символ ":".
возможно в edge проблема не только в этом, но в любом случае он не может запустить загруженный проект.
пробовал переустанавливать не помогло

Comment: Tomcat GUI Manager хорошо работает в Chrome. Какие файлы (логи) вы смотрели? Что значит "ничего не происходит": страница продолжает грузиться? Пробовил очищать кэш браузера?

Comment: логи которые пишутся в терминале томкэта.
Да,страница начинает грузиться и продолжает до бесконечности(скорее всего, я ждал максимум пол часа) 
Да,очистить кэш это первое что я сделал

Comment: А что в других лог-файлах? Есть ошибки?

Comment: нет,и оказывается загрузка не вечная
через некоторое время он предоставляет страницу авторизации но после ввода данных и отправки их он снова начинает грузится